# JQuery:Datepicker: Only last field has prev/next buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am trying to use JQUery-UI-datepicker. The files are included and the datepicker is displaying and working fine. However the prev/next/Today buttons are working only at the last input field marked as 'crud_date' for all others the datepicker works, but without this functionality. I have this problem on multiple pages, the id's given to the text fields are unique.

Further note: I am using a frame based approach, each frame includes the same JS-scripts. However in theory this should not be a problem as they are all separate dom modules. 
Further note: Sometimes I call the init functions multiple times, but even if it is initialised once the same problem occurs.

I have a webpage with markup like this:

```
<input type='text' id='start' class='crud_date' value='01.02.2015'>
<input type='text' id='ende' class='crud_date' value='10.02.2015'>
```

and in my JS file I initialize like this:

```
function init() {
  // some other stuff
  $('crud_date').datepicker();  
}

$(document).ready(init());
```

Comment: add a fiddle for better understanding.

Comment: should be `$(document).ready(init); `

Comment: `$('.crud_date').datepicker();` - missing `.` before the class name

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/o5vwjt56/1/ - looks fine

Comment: Thanks a lot that was a fast response:-)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot. When copying to the fiddle I changed to CDN links. Seems I got a wrong version or spelling mistake in my old javascript files locally.